# combine states of 2 redux stores

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have 2 stores, one about properties and one about owners.
Each property is owned by one or more owners, and I have to group the properties by owner. So like a map structure Map<Owner, Property[]>.

How to I retrieve both objects you ask? Redux selectors!

For properties I have a facade which has a selector

```
properties$ = this.store$.select(PropertySummarySelectors.selectProperties);
```

This is what is used now, to show a list of all properties on a page, now we have to add a tab, which will group the properties by owner. Why doesn't property have data about the owner, the owner is human and we can't store personal information on our side, privacy stuff.

In another store for owners, we also have a facade, which has a selector that I need

```
 ownersOfProperty$ = (propertyId) => this.store$.select(OwnerSelectors.selectOwnerForProperty, propertyId);
```

This will return a list of owners for the given property using the following selector:

```
  export const selectOwnerForProperty = createSelector(
    selectOwnerForProperty,
    (ownersPerProperty, propertyId) => ownersPerProperty[propertyId] || []
  );
```

So when calling the OwnerFacade, I get an Observable.

My idea was, when calling the property$ selector, for every object in that list, call the other facade to get the owners.

```
this.property$ = this.propertySummaryFacade.properties$.pipe(
        map(properties => properties.map(
            async property => {
              property.owners = await this.ownerFacade.ownerOfProperty$(property.id);
              return property;
            })
        )
    );
```

It doesn't resolve it, it looks ugly. How to I combine these 2 states for 2 stores correctly, without extending my Property object on the backend side, which is again not easy due to privacy regulation.

Comment: I think it would be much easier if you rewritten your code into a example in English only. It i shard to understand with the Dutch.

Comment: understandable, it gives more context about the functional side when you can actually relate to the situation, my bad :)

Comment: Thanks, thats more clear - what is the structure of the stores you're talking about? Is it like `Owner { propertyIds: string[] }` and `Property { id: string }`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a selector that combines both entities.

```
const selectCombine = createSelector(
  selectEntities1,
  selectEntitities2,
  (ent1, ent2) => /* combine both into a single object */
)
```

Use that selector as a "base" selector

```
const selectOne = (id) => createSelector(selectCombine, combine => combine[id])
```

Use the `selectOne` selector in components.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you are definitely on to something. Lets say the first selector is "properties$" and the second "$ownersOfProperty". The first are all the properties and the second are only the owners of one property, I can't combine them. Should I create a selector to only select 1 property?